# Having trouble with getElementsByTagName(blockquote)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get it to return "ha, awesome" followed by the index of the word "awesome"

HTML:

```
<blockquote id = "blocky">

ha, awesome<br>

</blockquote>
```

JS:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName(blockquote).innerHTML ;
var n = x.indexOf("awesome");
document.getElementsByTagName(blockquote).innerHTML = x + "<br>" + n;
```

If I change the JS to this, it works

```
var x = document.getElementById("blocky").innerHTML ;
var n = x.indexOf("awesome");
document.getElementById("blocky").innerHTML = x + "<br>" + n;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mzrt/zaf98g8y/1/

Comment: Any reason for vulgar id names?

Comment: Summer, nice edit! my downvote is for immaturity.

Comment: Because I was frustrated, my apologies

Answer (score 5):

Basically [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) will return a `node list`, an array like object, you cannot access the property of a `node` from it directly, you have to use bracket notation to fetch the first node from it and then you can treat it as a node object,

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote')[0].innerHTML;
```

Since the element that you are targeting is an element with id, It is better to go with [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Answer (score 5):

First off, you need to pass it a string, not a variable (unless that variable contains a string).

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
```

Next, [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) returns a element collection, not a single element. You can get the first result using `[0]`.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote')[0];
```

Or you can iterate through all of the elements using a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var element = x[i];
  element.innerHTML = '...';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote')[0].innerHTML ;
var n = x.indexOf("awesome");
document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote')[0].innerHTML = x + "<br>" + n;
```

Get element by tag name returns a node list, so you have to tell whitch node you do want.
Also you should pass tagname between single quotes.